# Hi, I was learning about input in dart and i encountered The following issue

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:io';
void main(){
  print("What is your name: ");
  String username = stdin.readLineSync();
  print("Good afternoon ${username}, How Can I help you?");
}
```

Error: A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
String username = stdin.readLineSync();

The code is supposed to give an input and then an output = "Good afternoon, How can I help You"

Comment: put `!` after `readLineSync()`. It will be `String username = stdin.readLineSync()!;`

Comment: You can read about Dart's (and by virtue, Flutter's) null safety here https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: Yes, please, DO read about null safety and DON'T blindly put exclamation marks everywhere.